# Why is jQuery click function not working?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to use this function to trigger a file download from a hidden element. This is what I'm trying, but it doesn't seem to work. I have spent hours on this and have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

```
<?php 

echo '
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block m-b-10" onclick="getBill('.$billNumber.')">Bill of Lading</button>
   <a href="images/bol/'.$billNumber.'.pdf" style="display:none" id="billOfLading'.$billNumber.'" download></a>';

?>

<script>

function getBill(a){

        var billNumber = a;

        if(billNumber != ''){
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url:'includes/bolScraper.php',
                data:{billNum: billNumber},
                success:function(data){
                    if (data != "no_pdf") {

                        //alert(data)

                        $("#billOfLading" + a).click();

                    } else {

                      alert(data);

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

 </script>
```

Comment: Can you give us an error or expected vs actual behaviour you are getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery selectors return an array. You need to select the element to call the click function in this way. Use index 0 to select the first matching element.

```
$("#billOfLading" + a)[0].click();
```

Fiddle example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dk9fng2L/)

Comment: What took me hours, it took you less than 5 minutes lol! Thank you, David! That was the problem.